# Can we inherit a custom variable defined in a class in another class?

Tags: css, css-variables

I've been going through the basic CSS tutorials and I had a small confusion. I would appreciate any help with this. Below are two examples to demonstrate what is causing the confusion

> **Scenario 1:** Inheriting a variable from `:root`

```css
:root {
  --red-color: red;
}
.red-box {
  background: red;
  background: var(--red-color);
  height: 200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-box"></div>
```

> **Scenario 2:** Inheriting a variable from another class. [I HAVE CONFUSION WITH THIS CASE]

```css
.penguin {

  /* change code below */
  --penguin-skin: gray;
  --penguin-belly: white;
  --penguin-beak: orange;
  /* change code above */

  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.penguin-top {
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
  background: var(--penguin-skin, gray);
  width: 50%;
  height: 45%;
  border-radius: 70% 70% 60% 60%;
}

.penguin-bottom {
  top: 40%;
  left: 23.5%;
  background: var(--penguin-skin, gray);
  width: 53%;
  height: 45%;
  border-radius: 70% 70% 100% 100%;
}

.right-hand {
  top: 0%;
  left: -5%;
  background: var(--penguin-skin, gray);
  width: 30%;
  height: 60%;
  border-radius: 30% 30% 120% 30%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.left-hand {
  top: 0%;
  left: 75%;
  background: var(--penguin-skin, gray);
  width: 30%;
  height: 60%;
  border-radius: 30% 30% 30% 120%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.right-cheek {
  top: 15%;
  left: 35%;
  background: var(--penguin-belly, white);
  width: 60%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 70% 70% 60% 60%;
}

.left-cheek {
  top: 15%;
  left: 5%;
  background: var(--penguin-belly, white);
  width: 60%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 70% 70% 60% 60%;
}

.belly {
  top: 60%;
  left: 2.5%;
  background: var(--penguin-belly, white);
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 120% 120% 100% 100%;
}

.right-feet {
  top: 85%;
  left: 60%;
  background: var(--penguin-beak, orange);
  width: 15%;
  height: 30%;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(-80deg);
  z-index: -2222;
}

.left-feet {
  top: 85%;
  left: 25%;
  background: var(--penguin-beak, orange);
  width: 15%;
  height: 30%;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(80deg);
  z-index: -2222;
}

.right-eye {
  top: 45%;
  left: 60%;
  background: black;
  width: 15%;
  height: 17%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.left-eye {
  top: 45%;
  left: 25%;
  background: black;
  width: 15%;
  height: 17%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sparkle {
  top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
  background: white;
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.blush-right {
  top: 65%;
  left: 15%;
  background: pink;
  width: 15%;
  height: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.blush-left {
  top: 65%;
  left: 70%;
  background: pink;
  width: 15%;
  height: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.beak-top {
  top: 60%;
  left: 40%;
  background: var(--penguin-beak, orange);
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.beak-bottom {
  top: 65%;
  left: 42%;
  background: var(--penguin-beak, orange);
  width: 16%;
  height: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

body {
  background:#c6faf1;
}

.penguin * {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="penguin">
      <div class="penguin-bottom">
        <div class="right-hand"></div>
        <div class="left-hand"></div>
        <div class="right-feet"></div>
        <div class="left-feet"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="penguin-top">
        <div class="right-cheek"></div>
        <div class="left-cheek"></div>
        <div class="belly"></div>
        <div class="right-eye">
          <div class="sparkle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="left-eye">
          <div class="sparkle"></div>
```

**My Question:**

I have clearly seen the tutorials mentioning that we can make use of variables from `:root` in other classes, but as per the example in Scenario 2 I am not able to understand how is the variable inherited from one class to another? I am asking this since I have not seen this mentioned specifically and I just want to be sure about my knowledge.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: The HTML Structure will decide. CSS only isn't enough so share the HTML too. If penguin is an ancestor of penguin-top then the inheritance is logical

Comment: Yes give me 1 minute, i will share it right away.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have added the full CSS for reference. Can you check and help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/):

> Custom properties are **ordinary properties**, so they can be declared on any element, are resolved **with the normal inheritance and cascade rules**, can be made conditional with @media and other conditional rules, can be used in HTML’s style attribute, can be read or set using the CSSOM, etc.

And also:

> Inherited: **yes**

So it's not about the inheritance from another class but the usual inheritance from a parent (or ancestor) element exactly like any inherited property.

In your case `penguin-top` is a child of `penguin` so it will inherit its custom properties.

---

Worth to note that `:root` is the `html` element which is the ancestor of all the elements that's why all them will logically inherit custom property defined inside `:root`

Comment: So basically this is one of those times where an HTML decides whether a class is `parent` and if it is `parent`, it's custom variables can be used in child classes? Am i getting it correctly ?

Comment: @mishsx yes kind of. SImply consider them like any property. Take the example of `color`. If you set it `color:red` to an element all its child will be red. Any element outside will not get affected by the red coloration

Comment: Last clarification - When you say kind of, I just want to be sure whether `inheritance` is the right word that goes while understanding CSS because in some websites I have seen that CSS does not have inheritance like the way we have in OOPS languages. What is your comment on that?

Comment: Basically, if I am getting you right, you mean to say that a class becomes an ancestor/ child based on how the HTML is structured and when the relationship is established, an inheritance of `attributes` follows. Child classes can use the attributes of parent classes.

Comment: @mishsx yes inheritance is the right word but it has nothing to do with inheritance in OOP languages. Here we inherit values. In OOP we inherit the variables but values can be different since each instance of an element is different (unless we consider the static variables which is another story)

Comment: @mishsx don't think about classes. Simply find the concerned element to identify inheritance. A class can be used in a lot of places so for some element you can have inheritance and for other not. Simply find your element inside the HTML see the hierarchy and you will identify what values are inherited

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this. It is all clear now.